# Pop out Google Picker from IFRAME in Google Sites Apps Script Gadget?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sites, google-picker

So I made this google apps script to use the google picker on my google sites webpage. The apps script is inserted into the webpage via the google apps script gadget. This all functions as I intended, however, it does not behave the way I'd like it to or expected. Everything is rendered inside the requisite IFRAME. And from what I can find and tried, this has to be the case (please correct me if I'm wrong). This requires me to provide the screen real estate to show the picker even when it's not visible -  which is pretty poor design. Does anyone know a way around this? That is, to make the picker modal to or pop out of the IFRAME instead stuck inside it?

Comment: Are you using HTML Service with the Apps Script project?

Comment: There wont be a way areound this because the picker only works well on iframe. Give it a try with the other modes.

Comment: @SandyGood: Yes, I'm using the HTML Service. Correct me if I'm wrong, but that is the only way to run the required JavaScript on a Google Sites webpage.

Comment: @ZigMandel: I assume you're referring to the sandboxing mode. EMULATED and NATIVE don't work. The picker never appears. For me anyways.

Comment: Yes i couldnt get it to work in those either but i think those would have been the only options.